# Material multiselect

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have material multi select control which I am using to select multiple resources for a certain task. For adding resources it is working fine but when it comes to edit I am unable to select the default resources which already working on that task. I have tried different solutions but could not succeeded. Any help would be highly appreciated.

```html
<h2 mat-dialog-title>{{title}}</h2>

<mat-dialog-content [formGroup]="form">
  
  <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
    <mat-label>Resources</mat-label>
    <mat-select formControlName="resource" multiple>
      <mat-option *ngFor="let resource of resources" [value]="resource">{{resource.name}}</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
 
</mat-dialog-content>

{{selectedResources | json}}

<mat-dialog-actions>
    <button class="mat-raised-button"(click)="close()">Close</button>
    <button class="mat-raised-button mat-primary"(click)="save()">Save</button>
</mat-dialog-actions>
```

```html
export class TaskAllocationComponent implements OnInit {

  form: FormGroup;
  selectedResources: User[];
  title: string;
  
  resources: User[] = [
    { 
      id: 1,
      image: '',
      name: 'Resource 1',
      initials: 'R1'
    },
    { 
      id: 2,
      image: '',
      name: 'Resource 2',
      initials: 'R2'
    },
    { 
      id: 3,
      image: '',
      name: 'Resource 3',
      initials: 'R3'
    },
    { 
      id: 4,
      image: '',
      name: 'Resource 4',
      initials: 'R4'
    },
    { 
      id: 5,
      image: '',
      name: 'Resource 5',
      initials: 'R5'
    },];

  constructor(
      private fb: FormBuilder,
      private dialogRef: MatDialogRef<TaskAllocationComponent>,
      @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) data) {

        this.title = data.name;
        this.selectedResources = data.resource as User[];
  }

  ngOnInit() {
      this.form = this.fb.group({
        resource: [this.selectedResources, Validators.required]
      });
      this.form.controls['resource'].setValue(this.selectedResources);
      
  }



  save() {
      this.dialogRef.close(this.selectedResources);
      
  }

  close() {
      this.dialogRef.close(this.selectedResources);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're comparing object references, and not value

you can pass a comparewith function to the mat-select

```
<mat-select formControlName="resource" [compareWith]="compareUser" multiple>
```

and in your ts

```
compareUser(user1, user2) {
  return user1 && user2 ? user1.id === user2.id : false;
}
```